# Unable to add CNN Layer after Embedding Layer Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have 7 categorical Featues
And i am trying to add A CNN Layer after Embedding Layer

My first Layer is input Layer
Second Layer is Embedding Layer
Third Layer I want to add a Conv2D Layer

I've tried input_shape=(7,36,1) in Conv_2D but that didn't work

```
input2 = Input(shape=(7,))
embedding2 = Embedding(76474, 36)(input2)

# 76474 is the number of datapoints (rows)
# 36 is the output dim of embedding Layer

cnn1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(embedding2)
flat2 = Flatten()(cnn1)
```

But i'm getting this error

```
 Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected 
 ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 7, 36]
```

Comment: You need to use 1D Convolution because your data is one dimensional. Second, using 1D conv only makes sense if input data is a sequence where the order of elements is important and signifies meaning (e.g. sequence of words, sequence of genomes, sequence of audio samples). If the seven categorical features does not have a sequential relationship with each other, then using convolution does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of an embedding layer is 3D, namely `(samples, seq_length, features)`, where `features = 36` is the dimensionality of the embedding space, and `seq_length = 7` is the sequence length. A `Conv2D` layer requires an image, which is usually represented as a 4D tensor `(samples, width, height, channels)`.

Only a `Conv1D` layer would make sense, as it also takes 3D-shaped data, typically `(samples, width, channels)`, and then you need to decide if you want to do convolution across the sequence length, or across the features dimension. That's something you need to experiment with, which in the end is to decide which is the "spatial dimension" in the output of the embedding